# az webapp log tail - skip existing logs

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am using the command `az webapp log tail` to follow my app service logs.

Usually it prints a ton of existing logs before it tails the current ones.
Is there a way to just follow logs like real `tail -f` does?

Answer (score 0):

No there is nothing something it gives option in cli.  Actually when we query the log then it start from connection time and then start giving the result. You can analyse the same azure portal log stream of web app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean with it starts from connection time? Is this the time when the service is created?

Comment: There is chance of time difference b/w connection and display time on command because this trail comand always gives the latest stream only

Comment: If it is the time, I connect using `az webapp log tail` it i kind of strange. Because I usually get spammed with logs from a week ago. Maybe it makes a difference that I use webapp with container on linux with blob storage as log storage.